# Template Class Type Sizing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, templates, sizeof, circular-buffer

I have written a template class for a circular buffer:

```
template <class T> class CRingBuffer { /* ... */ };
```

Some of the operations this class performs rely on an accurate evaluation of the size of `T`.  This seems to work okay when `T` is `BYTE` (i.e. `sizeof(T) == 1`, check).  However, when I try to use the same class where `T` is `DWORD`, for some reason `sizeof(T)` evaluates to 16.  The last time I checked, a double-word is 4 bytes, not 16.  Does anyone know why this is happening?  Thanks.

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

I can't post *all* the code due to its proprietary nature, but here is the class declaration and the function definition in question:

```
template <class T> class CRingBuffer
{
#pragma pack( push , 1 )                // align on a 1-byte boundary

typedef struct BUFFER_FLAGS_tag
{
    T * pHead;                          // Points to next buffer location to write
    T * pTail;                          // Points to next buffer location to read
    BOOL blFull;                        // Indicates whether buffer is full.
    BOOL blEmpty;                       // Indicates whether buffer is empty.
    BOOL blOverrun;                     // Indicates buffer overrun.
    BOOL blUnderrun;                    // Indicates buffer underrun.
    DWORD dwItemCount;                  // Buffer item count.
} BUFFER_FLAGS, *LPBUFFER_FLAGS;

#pragma pack( pop )                     // end 1-byte boundary alignment

    // Private member variable declarations
private:
    T * m_pBuffer;                      // Buffer location in system memory
    T * m_pStart;                       // Buffer start location in system memory
    T * m_pEnd;                         // Buffer end location in system memory
    BUFFER_FLAGS m_tFlags;              // Buffer flags.
    DWORD m_dwCapacity;                 // The buffer capacity.

    // CRingBuffer
public:
    CRingBuffer( DWORD items = DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE );
    ~CRingBuffer();

    // Public member function declarations
public:
    DWORD Add( T * pItems, DWORD num = 1, LPDWORD pAdded = NULL );
    DWORD Peek( T * pBuf, DWORD num = -1, DWORD offset = 0, LPDWORD pWritten = NULL );
    DWORD Delete( DWORD num, LPDWORD pDeleted = NULL );
    DWORD Remove( T * pBuf, DWORD num = 1, LPDWORD pRemoved = NULL );
    void Flush( void );
    DWORD GetItemCount( void );
    BYTE GetErrorStatus( void );

    // Private member function declarations
private:
    void IncrementHead( LPBUFFER_FLAGS pFlags = NULL );
    void IncrementTail( LPBUFFER_FLAGS pFlags = NULL );
};

template <class T> void CRingBuffer<T>::IncrementHead( LPBUFFER_FLAGS pFlags )
{
    ASSERT(this->m_pBuffer != NULL);
    ASSERT(this->m_pStart != NULL);
    ASSERT(this->m_pEnd != NULL);
    ASSERT(this->m_tFlags.pHead != NULL);
    ASSERT(this->m_tFlags.pTail != NULL);

    pFlags = ( pFlags == NULL ) ? &(this->m_tFlags) : pFlags;

    // Verify overrun condition is not set.
    if ( pFlags->blOverrun == FALSE )
    {
        pFlags->pHead += sizeof(T); // increament buffer head pointer
        pFlags->blUnderrun = FALSE; // clear underrun condition

        // Correct for wrap condition.
        if ( pFlags->pHead == this->m_pEnd )
        {
            pFlags->pHead = this->m_pStart;
        }

        // Check for overrun.
        if ( pFlags->pHead == pFlags->pTail )
        {
            pFlags->blOverrun = TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem described above occurs when `pFlags->pHead += sizeof(T);` of `IncrementHead` is executed.

Comment: Impossible to say definitively without seeing the class template's implementation, but alignment/padding is a guess.

Comment: Can you provide a small code snippet that demonstrates the problem, preferably one that is compilable without any other dependencies?

Comment: Post the actual code in which you are doing `sizeof(T)`, and the full definition of your class.

Comment: Something could be re-typedefing DWORD for you, but there's no way to tell because of the extremely limited information we have.

Comment: I'm headed out the door.  I'll post some code for this when I get in first thing tomorrow morning.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay, folks, I've added code to the OP.

Comment: Whoever voted to close this post, a reason would be nice.

Comment: In VS, `DWORD` is defined as `typedef unsigned long DWORD;`. Are you using the correct `DWORD`? Maybe a library changed the typedef or even `#define`d it? Maybe try `CRingBuffer<unsigned long>` instead to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, this is really simple after all :)

Without realising it, in `pFlags->pHead += sizeof(T);` you use pointer arithmetic. `pHead` is a pointer to `T`, and when you increase it by `sizeof(T)`, it means you move it forward by that many elements of type `T`, and not by that many bytes as you thought. So the size of `T` gets squared. If your goal is to move the pointer to the next element of the buffer, you should just increment it by 1: `pFlags->pHead += 1;`

Comment: You win the Eagle Eye award!  Thanks!